# Android resource linking failed error: resource style/CardView error: failed linking references

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

Am using androidx support library, Included the library for

> com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05

am getting the error while building the application, I haven't used any card view in my application.

```
Android resource linking failed

error: resource style/CardView (aka com.app.myapp:style/CardView) not found.
error: style attribute 'attr/cardElevation (aka com.app.myapp:attr/cardElevation)' not found.

error: style attribute 'attr/cardBackgroundColor (aka com.app.myapp:attr/cardBackgroundColor)' not found.

error: style attribute 'attr/cardCornerRadius (aka com.app.myapp:attr/cardCornerRadius)' not found.

error: failed linking references.
```

Already tried using [SO Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895857/failed-to-find-style-cardview-style-in-current-theme-cardview-not-working-in/50895887) ,[SO Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035063/android-resource-linking-failed) ,[SO Thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186009/error-compiling-android-app-with-material-components-and-androidx)

But haven't found any solution yet.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' // Included
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
    implementation project(':volley-master')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

I can't able to use any view with "**com.google.android.material**" same error, please help me solve it.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Have you added  `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1' ` this lib

Comment: can you provide some code, may be your xml file and the gradle file

Comment: I haven't used any card view in my project, updated the question with my dependencies.

Comment: You're not using any CardViews? The error shows its expecting cardviews parameters in the style attribute. Make sure your RecyclerView is not using cardviews, if you're using cardviews.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to remove the below dependencies as `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05` already have them and it will automatically pull the correct versions.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
// Remove it also if you are not using anything from the legacy support library.
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Also, make sure that the `compileSdkVersion` is **28** which you have already done.

*After resolving the issues, you can try again to use the specific versions one by one if required.*

Answer (score 0):

Probably that is a problem with themes and styles. Probably one of your libraries is expecting that style to be available and it's not finding it.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
</style>
```